# OSPFv3 (newer commands) not working in Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, router, ospf, ipv6, packet-tracer

The command

> router ospfv3 1

is not working in the Cisco Packet Tracer (Router: 2811).

Does it work somehow or are the IOS version just not up-to-date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packet Tracer is fairly limited in many ways. It emulates IOS, but it is not IOS. OSPFv3 was created to add support for IPv6. Assuming Packet Tracer supports IPv6, and you have enabled `ipv6 unicast routing`, the you could try to enable OSPFv3 with something like:

```
ipv6 router ospf 1
```

The OSPFv3 router configuration is also different. Instead of using network statements to tell OSPF which interfaces are participating in the OSPF process, you use OSPF commands directly on the interface configurations. For example:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ipv6 address 2001:db8::1/64
 ipv6 ospf 1 area 0
!
```

If your Packet Tracer doesn't support OSPFv3, you could try to update it, but you may need to run something with a real IOS, like GNS3.

Comment: You can use either `ipv6 router ospf ...` or `router ospfv3 ...` command as long the IOS supports both of them (see my answer below). If the IOS version only supports `ipv6 router ospf ...`, but `router ospfv3 ...` (newer command) then it is because IOS version is earlier than 15.1(3)S and 15.2(1)T. And the question is about this newer command.

Comment: @HungTran, yes, on IOS, but the question is about Packet Tracer, not IOS. Packet Tracer only supports a subset of IOS commands. It is specifically designed for CCNA. To run advanced things, you must use something more advanced, or use real IOS on something.

Answer (score 2):

This command was introduced in IOS Release 15.1(3)S and 15.2(1)T and later releases. You can check the command history at [IPv6 Commands](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/command/ipv6-cr-book/ipv6-r1.html#wp3277633316).

[image]

If you are using an earlier IOS image, it would not support.